# Window management shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager, layout

I've got a single massive monitor at home, and I've decided to mimic the Windows 7 window tiling shortcuts. I found a few guides online using `wmctrl`, and it's going well, save one thing: maximized windows don't respond to it.

```
gconftool-2 
--type string 
--set /apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/command_1 
"wmctrl 
   -r :ACTIVE: 
   -e 0,
      0,0,
      `xwininfo -root | grep Width | awk '{ print ($2/2)}'`,
      `xwininfo -root | grep Height | awk '{ print $2 }'`"
```

(*I've added line returns to make an otherwise massive one-liner readable.*) I've bound this to a hotkey and it works, unless the window is maximized. Any ideas on how to fix this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, if you first unmaximize it:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,$(xwininfo -root | grep Width | awk '{print ($2/2)}'),$(xwininfo -root | grep Height | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tonight when I get home and mark resolved when it works.

Comment: So I tried that and it doesn't work. I'm using metacity as a window manager, could that be the problem?

Comment: It's possible that you need the keybinding to be just one command, so try using bash with the -c option: `/bin/bash -c "COMMAND"`

Comment: Yeah, just tested it - it doesn't work as keybinding if you use the double ampersand, but works if you feed it as command string to bash.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been the problem. Sorry I didn't get back on this sooner, I didn't notice the comments.